# How to sort and count wrt a string

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

This is my input file.

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *5555555555 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *2222222222 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *3333333333 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [BBBBB]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *6666666666 [AAAAA]
```

Let's consider the above input as *input.gz*, how to get the count of *9999999999 with last column as [AAAAAA]

I need a script using SED or AWK or GREP.

Expected output should be:

```
5
```

What if the above input has the last column extended to a new line? like:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *5555555555 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA  
zzzzzzzzzzzz xxxxxxxx yy]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *2222222222 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *3333333333 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [AAAAA]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *9999999999 [BBBBB]
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss string *6666666666 [AAAAA]
```

In the above case, won't it be difficult to use AWK? How to overcome this using SED?

I'm sorry for editing it again. What if the 10-digit number is unknown? like *9999999999 is unknown, can we find out the number of times *NNNNNNNNNN is occuring with last column as [AAAAA]?

Comment: wrt `In the above case, won't it be difficult to use AWK? How to overcome this using SED?`. You have been misinformed. awk is specifically **designed** to operate on multi-line records. No exaggeration, sed hasn't been an appropriate tool to use on multi-line text since the mid-1970s when awk was invented. Really **think** about the most difficult input cases you need to handle and [edit] your question to show those plus the expected output given that input because right now the sample input you are providing doesn't seem to reflect worst cases of what you are describing.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat input_file | grep '[*]9999999999 \[AAAAA\]$' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 awk '$NF ~ /\[A+\]/ && $(NF1)~/\*9+/' input | wc -l
```

For the sake of simplicity, I use the `wc`-command to do the counting. Of course, this could be implemented in awk, too:

```
 awk '$NF ~ /\[A+\]/ && $(NF1)~/\*9+/{counter++}END{print counter}' input
```

**Update:** How to list the number of occurrences for each number

```
 awk '$NF ~ /\[A+\]/{ar[$(NF-1)]++}END{for(key in ar){print key,ar[key]}}' input
```

Output:

```
*2222222222 1
*6666666666 1
*5555555555 1
*3333333333 1
*9999999999 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just with one grep:

```
grep -c "\*9999999999.*\[AAAAA\]$" inputfile
```

When you have the input split over 2 lines (sometimes) but `[AAAAA` still on the first, you can try

```
grep -c "\*9999999999.*\[AAAAA" inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v key='*9999999999' '$NF=="[AAAAA]" && $(NF-1)==key {c++} END{print c}' file
5
```

if the last field is split into two lines, by definition it won't be equal to "[AAAAA]"